# Error "invalidPayload" with Microsoft Azure OpenAI fine-tuning

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services

When wanting to run a fine-tune request via the REST API I get the following error message:

```
"error": {
    "code": "invalidPayload",
    "message": "The fineTune field is required."
  }
```

Also, in the fine-tuning wizard I get a message saying "No models are available. Please check your access or try again later." [Screenshot of Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L6EYG.png)

Does anyone know what the problem is? Do I need another subscription?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you may not have the correct subscription level for Azure OpenAI. You may need to upgrade your subscription in order to use the fine-tuning feature.